# Firebase FCM token generate issues

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

NativeFirebaseError: [messaging/unknown] The operation couldn’t be completed. No APNS token specified before fetching FCM Token

Hello, i am a beginner for IOS and react-native. I cannot find the solution past two days.Someone help me.thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6893.

Comment: this is not enough information to really help - are you going native or Expo? Packages installed the right way? Can you show the code? maybe the package.json? https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup